# Squid as an explicit & terminated forward proxy / bridge

Tags: ssl, proxy, https, squid

Background: we've got some "old" IoT devices running an older SSL stack that must connect to a newer server over HTTPS.

We'd like to setup a forward proxy / bridge so that:

1. Device uses its own terminated TLS to proxy (using old SSL)
2. Device sends HTTP/CONNECT with remote server URL (https) (+basic.authentication)

   - note: remote server URL is unknown / dynamic, hence pushed with CONNECT.
3. Proxy uses its own terminated TLS to remote https server (using newer SSL)
4. Once established:

   - device sends plain-text HTTP/GET
   - proxy bridges plain-text traffic

We realize that this is not proper CONNECT tunneling as the device HTTP traffic is in plain-text (vs. tunneled TLS.)

Is this setup possible at all with Squid? we cannot find any doc, sample, for this use-case.

Comment: Step 1 and step 4 seem to contradict each other. Either the device is using its own old SSL (step 1) or it communicates in plain (step 4). If you just want to bridge the old SSL to the new TLS you can [use squid as an intercepting proxy](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept/SslBumpExplicit) - as long as squid can communicate with the older client and its older SSL.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thank you, I'll check the provided link.